# Polymer 1.x: Event listener scope of "this" object

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have added an event listener to my custom element for my `<iron-ajax>` call.

## Question

> How to I reference the `last-response` property of the `<iron-ajax>` element from an imperatively defined event listener?

*See comments in below code.*

custom-element.html

```
<template>
  ...
  <iron-ajax id="ajax" last-response="{{ajax}}"></iron-ajax>
  ...
<template>
<script>
  ...
  var t = this.$.ajax;
  t.addEventListener('response', function(e) {
    console.log(this.ajax); // undefined
    console.log(e); // Successfully logs response event object to console
  });
  ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `this` object in the scope of the event listener.

Introduce a new variable called `that` and apply the necessary scope as follows.

custom-element.html

```
  var that = this, // Adds scope
  t = this.$.ajax;
  t.addEventListener('response', function(e) {
    console.log(that.ajax); // Successful reference
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Javascript bind() to change the context of `this` in the function:

```
var t = this.$.ajax;
t.addEventListener('response', function(e) {
  console.log(this); // this now = t
  console.log(e); // Successfully logs response event object to console
}).bind(t);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

I have found two ways around this issue.

THe first (which I use when I have an iron-ajax-form is to attach the event listener to the custom element, and let it bubble up from the elements inside

so

```
this.addEventListener('iron-form-response',function(e) {
//this is correct here
});
```

The other method, used when I am using an iron ajax itself (ie call `this.$.ajax.generateRequest();`

is to set a function on my element to take the response - so

```
<iron-ajax
  id="validateuser"
  url="/api/validate_user"
  handle-as="json"
  method = "POST"
  body = "[[user]]"
  content-type="application/json"
  on-response="_validate"></iron-ajax>
```

and then inside `_validate` this still refers to my custom element.  In this case I don't need last_response, because the response is found like this

```
    _validate: function(e) {
    var response = e.detail.response;
    this.$.spinner.cancel();
    if (response.status) {
      //this user validated, so we are logged on
```